# How test multiple async process events with mocha.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, tdd, mocha.js

I try to test some async process events with mocha.js. The `it` method executes synchronious after `done` call by default. What is the strategy to test multiple async processes with mocha.js

```
describe('Game', function(done){
    var game = new Simulation.Game();
    this.timeout(5000);

    it('should start', function(done){
        game.on('start', function() {
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should log', function(done){
        game.on('log', function() {
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should end', function(done){
        game.on('end', function() {
            done();
        });
    });

    game.start();
});
```

Comment: This actually looks pretty good.  I don't think you need the done callback in the first line.  Assuming the game object actually fires each of these events, the tests should pass.  To fail a test you'd need to throw an error.  What problem are you running in to?

Comment: @remyp The problem is that the event subscription with ```.on``` executes too late. So that the next ```done()``` call s will never be fired. The test should fail if one of the event will not fire.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to use the before() hook to set up the test properly.  Try this:

```
describe('Game', function(){
    var game;
    this.timeout(5000);

    before(function(before_done) {
        game = new Simulation.Game();
        game.start();
        before_done();
    };        

    it('should start', function(done){
        game.on('start', function() {
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should log', function(done){
        game.on('log', function() {
           done();
        });
    });

    it('should end', function(done){
        game.on('end', function() {
           done();
        });
      });
});
```

Comment: He should be using `before`, but this is not his specific question.  He wants to know how to run the three `it` functions in parallel instead of sequentially.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to capture the result of the game callbacks:

```
describe('Game', function(done){
    var started, logged, ended;

    // Wrapping the initialization code in a before() block
    // allows subsequent describe blocks to be run if an
    // exception is thrown.
    before(function () {
        var game = new Simulation.Game();
        var game_on = function (event) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                game.on(event, function () {
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        };

        started = game_on('start');
        logged = game_on('log');
        ended = game_on('end');

        game.start();
    });

    this.timeout(5000);

    it('should start', function(){
        return started;
    });

    it('should log', function(){
        return logged;
    });

    it('should end', function(){
        return ended;
    });
});
```

The game_on function creates new promises for each event that resolve when the callbacks are called. The event handlers are registered correctly since the game has not yet started.

Inside the it-blocks the promises are just returned [since mocha will pass the test when they resolve](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises). If they do not resolve, they tests will reject with a timeout error.